# Shell commend not working for first time

Tags: makefile

I Am trying to writing a simple Makefile, which looks similar to below:

```
all:
    mkdir -p /home/developer/data/test/ && \ 
    cp /home/developer/data/sample.txt /home/developer/data/test/ && \
    export FILEPATH=$(dir $(shell find /home/developer/data/test/ -type f -name sample.txt))  && \
    echo $$FILEPATH
```

When I execute make for the first time echo is null(i.e Nothing get printed).
But when I execute same without removing the directory test it will print the proper path for echo.

But once you remove the test directory again and do make echo is null.

What is that I am doing wrong in this?

Comment: I think it should be `$FILEPATH` with single `$`, not two `$$` like you have there

Comment: @Entea This is in a make recipe. The doubled `$$` is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a timing issue.

You expect the entire contents of the recipe body to execute at recipe execution time but that's not what happens.

The make constructs inside the recipe body execute **first** and are expanded into the recipe body which is then run by the shell.

So `$(dir $(shell ...))` runs **before** any of the shell commands run and so there's nothing for `find` to find the first time.

Don't jump in and out of `make` contexts like that. If you want to run a shell command in the shell context then do so.

```
all:
    mkdir -p /home/developer/data/test/ && \ 
    cp /home/developer/data/sample.txt /home/developer/data/test/ && \
    FILEPATH=$$(dirname $$(find /home/developer/data/test/ -type f -name sample.txt)) && \
    echo $$FILEPATH
```

Also note that `export` there was not necessary and didn't do anything for you at all.